# "Name must be a string" error in Insert query using PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a strange error in this block:

```
   public static function saveUser($form)
{

    $connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cdiscodb", 'root', 'rthr'); // connexion à la BDD
    $connexion->setAttribute  (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ope_tartine_nl(first_name,last_name,email,created_date,updated_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    $cmd = $connexion->prepare($sql);
    $result = $connexion->exec(array($form['name'], $form['lastname'], $form['email'], date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));
}
```

the error is :

> Fatal error:  Function name must be a string

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ope_tartine_nl(first_name,last_name,email,created_date,updated_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
$cmd = $connexion->prepare($sql);
$result = $cmd->execute(array($form['name'], $form['lastname'], $form['email'], date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));
}
```

you have given as `$connexion->exec` whereas it should be `$cmd->exec(......)`

And Use `$cmd->execute` instead of `$cmd->exec`.

Comment: Thanks but i still have an error : Call to undefined method PDOStatement::exec()

Comment: do $result = $cmd->exececute(...) instead of $cmd->exec(...)